# Despite setting dimensions, custom view in ConstraintLayout ends up with size 0

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a custom view class (`EmptyTableView`) which normally works fine. However at one point in the program where I center this view within a  `ConstraintLayout`, the view suddenly becomes invisible. Further investigation shows that the view gets positioned at `(0, 0)` with the size `(0 x 0)`.
The `measureSpecs` inside my `onMeasure()` are `EXACTLY 0`. I couldn't find out what that means but [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727411/onmeasure-called-with-exactly-and-spec-size-0#22761084) said that that happens when you mess with measuring modes though I don't know why it happens in my view.
Here is the source code.

In my app, I have the view inside a `ConstraintLayout` called root and it's position can be altered by a `DragAndDrop` procedure.
My plan is letting the view have constraints to all 4 sides while the position is controlled via biases of the constraints. When I begin to drag the view, the the right and left constraints a deleted and the position is controlled with `setX()` and `setY()`. This this done with this method (Kotlin):

```
fun ConstraintSet.prepareConstraintsForDrag(table: View) {
        clear(table.id)
        connect(table.id, ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, table.left)
        connect(table.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, table.top)
    }
```

Then, when I end the `DragAndDrop`, I call the following from within my drag and drop callback in order to move the views layout to the x and y and then call restoreBiases() to connect all 4 sides again:

```
DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> {
                    shadowTouchPoint = null // Just an intern indicator for the drag
                    val draggedView = event.localState as View
                    with(draggedView) {
                        visibility = View.VISIBLE

                        rootConstraints.clone(root)
                        setMargin(id, ConstraintSet.START, x.toInt())
                        setMargin(id, ConstraintSet.TOP, y.toInt())
                        rootConstraints.applyTo(root)

                        translationX = 0f
                        translationY = 0f
                    }
                    rootConstraints.clone(root)
                    rootConstraints.restoreBiases(draggedView, options_guide, root.height.toFloat())
                    rootConstraints.applyTo(root)
                }
```

restoreBiases():

```
fun ConstraintSet.restoreBiases(table: View, sideGuide: Guideline, height: Float) {
        val xBias = table.x / (sideGuide.left - table.width).toFloat()
        val yBias = table.y / (height - table.height)

        center(table.id, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 0,
                sideGuide.id, ConstraintSet.START, 0, xBias)
        center(table.id, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0,
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0, yBias)
    }
```

The entire code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Zonico6/SeatingPlanner/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/zoniklalessimo/seatingplanner). `prepareConstraintsForDrag()` and `prepareBiases()` are located in `TableScene.kt`. The callback in `tabblePlan/ConstructEmptyTablePlan.kt` and `EmptyTableView.kt` in the `tablePlan` directory.

This is how it roughly looks inside the activity:

[image: After starting the activity]
[image: While dragging (the upper right is the dragshadow, there was my thumb while taking the picture, in the middle the actual view which I don't hide for debugging]
[image: After letting go of the dragged view, now the view is at position (0, 0) and has size (0 x 0)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to version 1.1.2 of `ConstraintLayout`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

I think that there may be problems with `center()` before this release. I don't think that this will solve your problem, but it may clear the way to finding the underlying issue. In other words, I think that you will see something different on your screen.

I can say that your guideline `options_guide` is somehow getting set to the width of the screen. Maybe this is the intent but, if it isn't, I would look into how this guideline is set and used.

Comment: This is intented, I can move it in to show a menu. Thank you very much for your tip and especially for taking the time for my verbose question!
I'm gonna try updating the dependency as soon as I can gonna keep this updated as well, thank you so much!

Comment: Ok. Try 1.1.2 anyway.

Comment: That's what I meant with updating the dependency :D
Dude thank you SO much I was never so happy about something not working ^^  
EDIT: Forgot the link https://imgur.com/KHEIkIO